# Git Commit creates a new Head - PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, commit

When I commit my changes using PyCharm, it creates new Head.
How can I prevent this?
Why does this happen?
(I'm not familiar with using git via terminal)

**Add:**
The problem was my understanding of git. With the understanding of what is head and how git works, now this question seems silly to me.

> **PS:** Understanding how git works under the hood is very important and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand, that actually HEAD is pointer to your last commit in branch. It is common practice (change head pointer due adding new commits). Of course, you can change location of HEAD, but it can lead to leaks of changes (In the case of new commits). If you want to mark some commits then you should create new branch or tag.

Comment: This is what I see, does it have to do anything with branches?   : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DtVn7J8-wYM3lwazdXRjB4Rzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As I understood, you just have created some changes meanwhile other programmers have made own. All you need is perform rebase or merge command to sync your changes (if you need current other changes) and continue to work

Comment: The last push to the repository was made by me.
Can we have a chat please?